# How to change a parameters in a predefined interface in JAVA?

Tags: java, multithreading, apache, numerical-methods, ode

I have recently implemented an ODE solver from the [Apache Commons Library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/ode.html). I find it very good I must say but I have some questions which relates partly to JAVA interfaces and partly to the toolbox itself. I am hoping one of you may be able to help me some of the way. I am using the example shown from the homepage.

They start defining the ODE function itself:

```
private static class CircleODE implements FirstOrderDifferentialEquations {

public double[] c;
public double omega;

public CircleODE(double[] c, double omega) {
    this.c     = c;
    this.omega = omega;
}

public int getDimension() {
    return 2;
}

public void computeDerivatives(double t, double[] y, double[] yDot) {
    yDot[0] = omega * (c[1] - y[1]);
    yDot[1] = omega * (y[0] - c[0]);
}

}
```

Then they instanciate the integrator and the model:

```
FirstOrderIntegrator dp853 = new DormandPrince853Integrator(1.0e-8, 100.0, 1.0e-10, 1.0e-10);
FirstOrderDifferentialEquations ode = new CircleODE(new double[] { 1.0, 1.0 }, 0.1);
```

from here they have some initial value and calculate from the initial value to some final state:

```
double[] y = new double[] { 0.0, 1.0 }; // initial state

dp853.integrate(ode, 0.0, y, 16.0, y); // now y contains final state at time t=16.0
```

**My Question: Now assume I want to change the value of omega from, lets say from t= 16 to t = 23.** How would I work around that?

**My proposals (which do not work):**

**Proposal 1:**
I thought about doing the variable `static`:

```
public static double omega;
```

but my intention is to run multithread at some point, so setting `omega` to static showed out to be a bad idea.

**Proposal 2:**
Then I thought about creating a new `interface` that could enable setter and getter methods in CircleODE, hereby allowing me to change the value of `omega` on the go.

```
public interface Circle{
public void setOmega(double myNewValueOfOmega);

}
```

The call of CircleODE would become:

```
private static class CircleODE implements FirstOrderDifferentialEquations, Circle
```

I thought "this is a pretty good idea, all i need to do now is call the set method like this:

```
ode.setOmega(newValueOfOmega);
```

**This is not possible** since `ode` actually is an instance of `FirstOrderDifferentialEquations` (I think) and hence my new method setOmega cannot be called.

Do you have any suggestions to how I would be able to change the value of Omega without creating a new instance of `ode`?

Comment: if `CircleODE` would implement both `FirstOrderDifferentialEquations` and `Circle`, why not use `CircleODE ode = new CircleODE();`? You'd then be free to use `setOmega()`.

Comment: Good point. I will try to implement and get back. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: @victorantunes, your suggestion actually seem to work. Do you have any comments in regards to Jaffar's suggestion? Whats the best?

Comment: other than a really small runtime overhead for type checking, I see no difference in your code example. If that's all you're really doing, then either will serve just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast it back to CircleODE just for setting Omega and call the method setOmega without creating a new instance.

```
FirstOrderIntegrator dp853 = new DormandPrince853Integrator(1.0e-8, 100.0, 1.0e-10, 1.0e-10);
FirstOrderDifferentialEquations ode = new CircleODE(new double[] { 1.0, 1.0 }, 0.1);

((CircleODE)ode).setOmega(newValueOfOmega);
```

For rest of the code ode will remain an instance of FirstOrderDifferentialEquations.

Secondly you can write a utility class/method to do the same but encapsulated.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jaffar. What is most suitable to use you think?

Comment: Utility Class will be more usable & maintainable

Comment: I ended up using victorantunes example and that actually seem to work.